# Error when fetching metadata after upgrading Breeze from 1.4.11 to 1.4.16

Tags: c#, breeze, entity-framework-6, single-page-application, hottowel

I upgraded Breeze from 1.4.11 to 1.4.16 using Nuget, and now I get this error when getting the metadata using manager.fetchMetadata():

```
Metadata query failed for: http://localhost:50015/breeze/Application/Metadata. Unable to either parse or import metadata: NamingConvention for this client property name does not roundtrip properly:DefaultIngredientCode-->defaultIngredientCode; [object Object]
```

That DefaultIngredientCode property is declared in the partial class of an Entity Framework table. It's NOT a column in a table. It's declared like this:

```
public string DefaultIngredientCode { get; set; }
```

Everything was working fine, until I upgraded Breeze Client and Server to version 1.4.16.

Are there changes that I have to do after the upgrade?

I'm using Hot Towel and Entity Framework 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug fix introduced into Breeze 1.4.14 ( this fragment below is from the release notes).

- D2610 - Handle casing correctly for unmapped properties.  Previously unmapped properties would not go thru the registered namingConvention when registered late. *Note: this could be a breaking change if you were counting on the previous 'errant' behavior*

My guess is that you have a 'DefaultIngredientCode' property declared in the *javascript* constructor of your entity class.  Since this name is NOT camelCased it does not roundtrip properly. If you change this property to 'defaultIngredientCode' your code should work properly.  NOTE: this is a client side change NOT a server side change.